# Using the correct/best solc version with Truffle and general tooling setup

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc

I haven't worked with Truffle/Solidity for a while and I am trying to get my environment/toolchain configure correctly. I have some questions regarding the compiler config.

I was originally not setting the compiler config options in `truffle-config.js` and recently set it to 5.5 which appears as if it caused Truffle to download a new Docker image, and compilation seems to have slowed down, or at least running the full test suite is quite a bit slower.

I am working on an a project and have been setting the pragma as

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
```

My truffle config block:

```
  // Configure your compilers
    compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.5",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
       optimizer: {
         enabled: false,
         runs: 200
       },
       evmVersion: "petersburg"
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

And my solc output:

```
solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.5.12+commit.7709ece9.Darwin.appleclang
```

Does this look correct? Are there any obvious improvements?

Project repo: https://github.com/alanwilhelm/upgradeable_token

Comment: Can you include the link to github direct? URL shorteners are not necessary here and often are a source a problems.

Comment: @Ismael Sure updated. Also updated the repo with a small crowdsale. I'm up to 68 passing tests now. I notice when I use a config for my compiler via truffle-config things compile and test very slowly. I think it is downloading a docker image with the correct solc version. I was commenting out the solc config in truffle-config during active development because it seems to use my local solc and move a lot faster. recommendations appreciated. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truffle is not using `solc`.

You can see what it IS using with

```
./truffle version
```

This is a little ambiguous, IMO.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
```

In practice, what I like to do is specify *exactly* what compiler to use for top-level contracts and `^` for inherited contracts and libraries. That way, the toolchain will emit an error at the first sign of an inconsistency.

For example:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.5;

import "./Something.sol";

contract MyContract is Something {
 ...
}
```

and

```
pragma solidify ^0.5.1;

contract Something {
  ...
}
```

That leaves no possibility of compiling, testing, deploying with inconsistent compiler versions and it will also save you a little time if you want to bump it up to a newer version at some point.

It will also *force* you to consistently select the right compiler when using tools like Remix. You'll be reminded - it's gotta be 0.5.5.

As an FYI, my understanding is that Truffle downloads `solcjs` the same way Remix does it, and this is why the installed `solc` compiler (standalone) is irrelevant to Truffle.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a great tip and the kind of info I am looking for. Thx!

Comment: Also good point. It's using solc-js. Truffle v5.1.8 (core: 5.1.8)
Solidity v0.5.12 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.1
Web3.js v1.2.1